# Firebase Admin SDK function not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm trying to set up email and password authentication in NodeJS using firebase, but i keep getting this error: `TypeError: firebase.auth(...).createUserWithEmailAndPassword is not a function`

Code:

```
var firebase = require('firebase-admin');

firebase.initializeApp({
  credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://my-app-name.firebaseio.com'
});

firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    console.log(errorMessage + errorCode);
    if (errorMessage) {
      res.status(500).send();
    } else {
      res.status(200).send();
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you included the necessary scripts / modules? https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Answer (score 3):

The code you're showing comes from the [web client SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account), not the Admin SDK. According to the [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user), the function from the Admin SDK is:

```
firebase.auth().createUser({
  email: email,
  password: password
}).then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log("Successfully created new user:", userRecord.uid);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error creating new user:", error);
  });
```

Comment: firebase.auth() is not the admin SDK that is firebase.